# MIME type of “text/plain” error after deploying on netlify custom domain from github

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify, appwrite

I developed a react JS website using Vite and appwrite for the backend which is running perfectly on localhost but when I am trying to host on Netlify it gives me the following error

“main.jsx:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of “text/plain”. Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.”

I bought a custom domain on Hostinger and changed the required settings to use Netlify DNS which showed successful on Netlify, but now is am getting this annoying error constantly. When I am checking the content type in the network it shows a content type of text/plain. Please help me resolve this error as this is for production.

Website Link:- rishi-bhumi.com

The website worked perfectly just before writing this post but for no reason automatically the problem started to occur again. It works fine in the following link https://main--velvety-kitten-5406fd.netlify.app/ but is not working for my custom domain.

I have tried to clear browser cache, mobile, laptop, different networks, different browsers, etc but doesn’t work at all.

Comment: Have you registered the jsx file extension with the mime type on your server?

Comment: @Pete can you tell me how to do that on appwrite, this is the first time i am using it.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used it - might be better asking a question on https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I don't see any jsx files being loaded directly while I browse your site at its custom domain (rather than the Netlify internal domain).  Can you share a URL that demonstrates the problem?  Also please be aware that you may get interesting results using the `main--sitename.netlify.app` url vs sitename.netlify.app directly (assuming your production branch is main), so might try skipping the `main--` part of the URL to be sure you are browsing the currently published production deploy at Netlify (comparing apples:apples since that is what is served at your custom domain)